# Can I charge my iPhone 13 with the Power brick from my Macbook M1 Air (2020)?

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, charging, power

So, I got a 30W charger with my M1 Macbook Air. Can I use it to charge my iPhone 13 without affecting its battery health more negatively, or I should go for a 12, or 20W charger?

Also, are there any charging tips to prolong the battery life? Like I should only charge to 80%, not charge it overnight, or it doesn't really matter.

Comment: more important than anything else when it comes to battery life is keeping the battery "cool". I.e. if you are in the hot sun outside put the phone inside a pocket or in the shade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a higher-rated charger with an iPhone.  Energy isn't 'pushed' into the phone, the phone takes what it needs. The rating is the maximum that the charger can provide.

As for prolonging the battery life: Apple has teams of engineers working on the software that manages the battery. There are algorithms that analyse your usage, and charge the battery accordingly. The "Optimize Battery Charging" setting already delays charging above 80%, if that fits your usage.

I'd say use it as you need. Because you want to have a phone you can use as you need, not one that you have to modify your behaviour for. Chances are, the phone's battery will last for three years or so -- whatever you do -- before you either replace the battery, or get a new phone.